# Sending logs via email using serverside javascript

Tags: javascript, email

I need to build a Javascript which scans a directory regularly and emails the log files to a group of people

I am not familiar with all Javascript frameworks, but from what I know client side javascript does not allow you to send an email without help from a client email application(like Outlook Express and such).

1. Are there any Javascript frameworks which provide such functionality via some API?
2. If there are no Javascript frameworks, can I use serverside Javascript to do what I want.

I am familiar with basic JavaScript (no frameworks and don't know anything about serverside JavaScript).

My rudimentary code is

```
function sendemail()
{
    var emailaddresses = ["address1@domain.com","address2@domain.com"..."addressn@domain.com"];
    /* list of email addresses to receive log files */

    // Assuming the log file is in C:\test, though it can be on a network location onanother server also
    var file=fopen("C:\\test\\log file.txt",0);
    var len = flength(file);
    var str = fread(file,len);
    fwrite(file, str);

    var href = "mailto:" + emailaddresses.splice(0, 1) + "?"
        + "cc=" + emailaddresses.join(",") + "&"
        + "subject= log files" + "&"
        + "body=Attached are the logs" + str;

    var windowMail = window.open(href, "_blank", "scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,width=10,height=10");
    if( windowMail )
    {
        windowMail.close();
    }
}
```

It is not working and certainly does not attach the logs(but copies their content into a variable and send the content as body of message which can cause issues with lot of mail clients like Outlook Express)

Did enough search to learn client side Javascript is not suited for this task as server side language such as PHP, ASP

Some links mention
how to attach a file 
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/scripting/Exsead8.aspx
and 
http://arstechnica.com/open-source/news/2009/11/w3c-publishes-draft-of-new-file-api-spec.ars
, but I want to know if there is another way using some framework API or serverside javascript.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Web-based javascript doesnt allow you to read the users harddrive, like you are doing right now.

Comment: Why does it need to be JavaScript?

Comment: I don't think you understand what Javascript is for. Also, you keep talking about serverside JS, but then try to open a new window? That makes no sense, sorry.

Comment: TJHeuvel, It was just an example. See this http://arstechnica.com/open-source/news/2009/11/w3c-publishes-draft-of-new-file-api-spec.ars where it explains some API is in the process of dong this.

Comment: Chris, There is a requirement hence, else i would have done much easier PHP and other options

Comment: Zanfa, I do understand what Javascript is for? Client side processing and validation as it was originally created. My example does not use serverside JS so the window opening. Again, the code was rudimentary. I was trying to gather ideas on how serverside JS can help me what I want. Any suggestions for that?

Comment: You might want to look at node.js. You can run JavaScript in a more server-like environment (like reading files, sending emails): http://nodejs.org/. I'm not experienced with emails in node.js but this might be a good start: http://blog.nodejitsu.com/sending-emails-in-node.

Comment: +1 on node.js. IMHO it's a little strange that you were given the requirement of using JS on the server, but that the requirement didn't mention how this was to be achieved. But anyway, node.js could be the right solution.